# In case of ANT, How to pass Classpath to child build.xml

Tags: ant, build

I have created an EAR project in Eclipse to be deployed on JBoss. In there I have created 4 projects, One EAR, under it one Hibernate project(data tier), one EJB project(bussiness tier) and Dyanamic Web Project(web project).
MBS(EAR)
-MBSData
-MBSEjb
-MBSWeb

I am creating ANT build.xml for this project. I have created individual build.xml from every project. I will be creating build.xml for MBS(EAR) project and in this build.xml, I will be calling child build.xml like

```
<target name="build" description="build all projects in reference to this project">
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${MBSData.location}" inheritAll="true" target="build"/>
</target>
```

Since in every build.xml the jboss_runtime_classpath is duplicated, I want to put it at one place. So I want to know how this classpath can be propagated to child build.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to define classpath in build.xml and [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) it every where. This is available in ant 1.8. (Probably available in earlier version. See comment from @ Oers )

I would not suggest the idea of defining a single classpath and use it every where. Each project should have well defined compile time dependency and runtime dependency(say for tests or running app using ant).  Having a big class path that is reused everywhere will lead to code from one area (say GUI) using code from another(say persistence)

Comment: import is older than 1.8, don't know exactly since when but I use this in ant 1.7

Comment: @ Oers : thanks. I edited the answer. I started using it after i moved to 1.8.